# SpriteKit SKSequence to make UI Buttons appear

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skaction

In a gameOverScene of my SpriteKit game, I have 3 buttons which appear on the screen.

I'm trying to make them "pop in", one after the other... I figured a neat way was to fade them in from 0 alpha to full.

I'm currently doing it like this:

```
    //animate in buttons
    restartButton.alpha = 0
    shareButton.alpha = 0
    exitButton.alpha = 0

    let bringInUIButtons = SKAction.sequence([
        SKAction.waitForDuration(1.0),
        SKAction(restartButton.runAction(SKAction.fadeInWithDuration(0.3))),
        SKAction.waitForDuration(1.0),
        SKAction(shareButton.runAction(SKAction.fadeInWithDuration(0.3))),
        SKAction.waitForDuration(1.0),
        SKAction(exitButton.runAction(SKAction.fadeInWithDuration(0.3))),
        ])

    runAction(bringInUIButtons)
```

But they all fade in at once... Even though, as part of my sequence I wait for a second in-between each Action.

I even tried this:

```
    //animate in buttons
    restartButton.alpha = 0
    shareButton.alpha = 0
    exitButton.alpha = 0

    let bringInUIButtons = SKAction.sequence([
        SKAction.waitForDuration(1.0),
        SKAction(restartButton.runAction(SKAction.fadeInWithDuration(0.3))),
        SKAction.waitForDuration(1.0),
        SKAction(shareButton.runAction(SKAction.fadeInWithDuration(0.6))),
        SKAction.waitForDuration(1.0),
        SKAction(exitButton.runAction(SKAction.fadeInWithDuration(0.9))),
        ])

    runAction(bringInUIButtons)
```

...and by changing the fade in duration, so each button takes longer to appear, but it doesn't look very good.

Am I using the `waitForDuration` incorrectly? I figured it would wait before starting the next action in the sequence?

How can I make the next button appear after the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're having each button run its own "fade in" action, which means they'll execute their actions in parallel. If you want them to appear one at a time in the scene, it's better to have the scene run the action. Here's my solution...

When you instantiate `restartButton`, `shareButton`, and `exitButton`, set their name properties as shown below:

```
restartButton.name = "restartButton"
shareButton.name = "shareButton"
exitButton.name = "exitButton"
```

You'll use these `name` properties to specify the button on which you want to run a "fade in" action using the `runAction(_:onChildWithName:)` method.
When it's time to fade the buttons in, use this set of actions:

```
let fadeIn = SKAction.fadeInWithDuration(1)
let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(1)

let bringInRestartButton = SKAction.runAction(fadeIn, onChildWithName: "restartButton")
let bringInShareButton = SKAction.runAction(fadeIn, onChildWithName: "shareButton")
let bringInExitButton = SKAction.runAction(fadeIn, onChildWithName: "exitButton")

let bringInUIButtons = SKAction.sequence([
  bringInRestartButton,
  wait,
  bringInShareButton,
  wait,
  bringInExitButton
])

runAction(bringInUIButtons)
```